# Merging tags [browser] and [web-browser]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags

Both [browser](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser) and [web-browser](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser) tags refer to the same thing and should be merged since there is no difference between them.

Qs tagged [browser](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/browser)
Qs tagged [web-browser](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/web-browser)

Comment: Alex, I think the synonym for this should be `web-browser` > `browser`. The site *is* aimed at Web Applications after all. What do you think about this?

Comment: Absolutely. Web-browser would be kind of redundant, since the whole site is about web apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been done and a synonym created for `web-browser` > `browser`